# Create an Excel Bell Curve for requests per second

Tags: excel, statistics, http-request

I run into this all the time. Server X is expected to handle Y transactions per day. Where Z% of transactions will occur over N hours.

What's the simplest way to create a bell curve \ graph in excel showing the requests per second.

I've looked up a number of examples using NormDist() etc. but quite honestly, I'm no math wiz and don't want to get into hours of statistical understanding in order to complete the task.

Comment: Do you have an actual dataset to work with or are you just looking for a theoretical graph with a bell curve shape?

Comment: I do not have a dataset. Only the clients request that we handle X transactions per day where 70% of requests happen over a Y period. I can do the math of course, but I'd like to create a bell curve showing the rates for visual effect.